# How can I place a brace in a relative position to two labels of different nodes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

For example, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[estilo/.style={rectangle,draw,node distance=0mm,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.5cm}]

    \tikzset
    {
        brace/.style= {decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=8pt}, decorate}
    }

    \node[estilo] (n1) [minimum width=4cm]{};
        \node[estilo] (n1-1)[ right=of n1.west, label=below:$i$ ]{};
        \node[estilo] (n1-2)[ left=of n1.east,  label=below:$j$ ]{};

    \draw [brace] (n1-1.south west) -- (n1-2.south east) 
        node[midway, label=below:{$ n = j - i + 1 $}]{};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I would like the brace to be located just below of the labels of nodes n1-1 and n1-2, but in a relative form.
**Any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give the `j` label a name (it is just a node) you can use its south anchor to place the line. The `perpendicular cs:` helps here to find the outer corner (the `i` and `j` are not so wide as 0.5cm). As the `j` node has a greater depth, it will also be used for the opposite end of the brace.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  estilo/.style={
    rectangle, draw, minimum size=+.5cm,
    outer sep=+0pt, node distance=+0pt},% or: node distance=-.5\pgflinewidth
  brace/.style= {decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=+8pt}, decorate}
]
  \node[estilo, minimum width=4cm] (n1){};
    \node[estilo, right=of n1, label=              below:$i$ ] (n1-1) {};
    \node[estilo, left=of n1,  label={[name=n1-2-j]below:$j$}] (n1-2) {};

  \draw [brace] (n1-2.south west |- n1-2-j.south) -- (n1-1.south east |- n1-2-j.south)
                 node[midway, below=+\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude]{$ n = j - i + 1 $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]